# How to refer to child of a child module in Maven

Tags: maven

I have following module structure.

```
  Project 
     -- datamodel
     -- server
          |---- ear
           ---- api
```

If I modify something in datamodel.I would like to only execute pom for datamodel.However 'ear' module is doing the final packaging.So, I end up executing datamodel and ear.
I tried following command, but did not work.

```
 mvn install -pl datamodel,server:ear.
```

How to refer to the child module of a child module?
I assume that whatever we are specifying after "-pl" are the artifactIds of the module that we want to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the `groupId:artifactId` not the folder name.

Comment: I doubt that but you should try `-X`.

Comment: Using a complete name(groupId:artifactId) works well.If the groupId is mycompany, following command works..... mvn install -pl datamodel,mycompany:ear. Not sure why datamodel worked without the 'groupId' prefix.

Comment: did you change the groupId somewhere in the tree?